# Android builds twice when using flutter flavours

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I recently upgraded Flutter from 2.2.x to 2.10.x.

All was working fine on 2.2.x. On the new version, iOS works properly, but Android is having issues, as it seems to be running the app build.gradle twice: a first time with the proper flavour, a second time with no flavour.

The command is `flutter run --flavor dev`

The error I get is:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Reading env from: .env.dev
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 8 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env
**************************
*** Missing .env file ****
**************************
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/guillaumeferron/Sites/TendoPay-App/android/app/build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Cannot invoke method split() on null object
```

As you can see, there is a double "Reading env from", which should not happen. The first run works fine and goes through, but gets killed by the second run that fails.

The faulty line (which is not the issue itself, but a consequence of the dual run) is:
`def flutterVersionCode = Double.parseDouble(project.env.get("APP_VERSION_ANDROID").split("\\.")[0]) * 10000 + Double.parseDouble(project.env.get("APP_VERSION_ANDROID").split("\\.")[1]) * 100 + Double.parseDouble(project.env.get("APP_VERSION_ANDROID").split("\\.")[2])`

My flutter doctor is:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-x64, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /Users/guillaumeferron/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (3 weeks ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/guillaumeferron/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 60.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 212.5284.31

[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

I've been looking around for a couple hours now, to no avail.
Flutter 2.10.x is not the problem itself, it is Android SDK 31 that is. Indeed, this only happens when I change the SDK version, unfortunately it is a required change in order to support the pub packages versions for 2.10.x.

If I println the different env variables I would get when having it as `APP_VERSION_ANDROID="0.2.3"` for instance, would be the first occurrence "0.2.3", and `null` the second, which triggers the error.

I have done all the flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter pub upgrade, gradle clean, etc..

Any help would be appreciated, as I did not find anything relevant online, and lack the Android dev expertise to debug it myself.

*Note: the flavour infrastructure I went for is https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this, after many hours of testing and research, what fixed it was to properly upgrade the Android version. So make sure that:

1. You open the project with Android Studio, and have all proper grade versions downloaded by going to File > Project Structure. Gradle should be v6.1.1 and Plugin v4.0.1
2. Set your kotlin version to v1.5.31 (https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version)
3. Have both your target and compile sdk version to 31

This should then work properly, and the gradle won't be executed a second time with no flavor.